# Corda: Party rejected session request as Requestor has not been registered

Tags: kotlin, corda

I've a Corda application that using M14 to build and run corda to run a TwoPartyProtocol where either parties can exchange data to reach a data validity consensus. I've followed [Corda flow cookbook](https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-M14.0/flow-cookbook.html) to build a flow.

Also, after reading the docs from several different corda milestones I've understood that M14 no longer needs flowSessions as mentioned in the [release notes](https://discourse.corda.net/t/cordapp-changes-introduced-by-milestone-12/1231) which also eliminates need to register services.

My TwoPartyFlow with inner FlowLogics:

```
class TwoPartyFlow{
   @InitiatingFlow
   @StartableByRPC
   open class Requestor(val price: Long,
                        val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>(){
       @Suspendable
       override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
           val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryNodes.single().notaryIdentity
           send(otherParty, price)
           /*Some code to generate SignedTransaction*/
       }
   }

   @InitiatedBy(Requestor::class)
   open class Responder(val requestingParty : Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>(){
          @Suspendable
          override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
              val request = receive<Long>(requestor).unwrap { price -> price }
              println(request)
              /*Some code to generate SignedTransaction*/
          }    
   }

}
```

But, running the above using startTrackedFlow from Api causes the above error:

```
Party CN=Other,O=Other,L=NY,C=US rejected session request: com.testapp.flow.TwoPartyFlow$Requestor has not been registered
```

I had hard time finding the reason from corda docs or logs since Two Party flow implementations have changed among several Milestones of corda. Can someone help me understand the problem here.

My API Call:

```
@GET
@Path("start-flow")
fun requestOffering(@QueryParam(value = "price") price: String) : Response{
        val price : Long = 10L
        /*Code to get otherParty details*/
        val otherPartyHostAndPort = HostAndPort.fromString("localhost:10031")
        val client = CordaRPCClient(otherPartyHostAndPort)
        val services : CordaRPCOps = client.start("user1","test").proxy
        val otherParty: Party = services.nodeIdentity().legalIdentity
        val (status, message) = try {
            val flowHandle = services.startTrackedFlow(::Requestor, price, otherParty)
            val result = flowHandle.use { it.returnValue.getOrThrow() }
            // Return the response.
            Response.Status.CREATED to "Transaction id ${result.id} committed to ledger.\n"
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST to e.message
        }
        return Response.status(status).entity(message).build()
}
```

My Gradle deployNodes task:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['build']) {
directory "./build/nodes"
networkMap "CN=Controller,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK"
node {
    name "CN=Controller,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK"
    advertisedServices = ["corda.notary.validating"]
    p2pPort 10021
    rpcPort 10022
    cordapps = []
}
node {
    name "CN=Subject,O=Subject,L=NY,C=US"
    advertisedServices = []
    p2pPort 10027
    rpcPort 10028
    webPort 10029
    cordapps = []
    rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": []]]
}
node {
    name "CN=Other,O=Other,L=NY,C=US"
    advertisedServices = []
    p2pPort 10030
    rpcPort 10031
    webPort 10032
    cordapps = []
    rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": []]]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the API call? You appear to be initiating an `InitiatorFlow`, which I don't see defined above.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated my question with API call and correct flow error.

Comment: How are you running the nodes to test the API?

Comment: Updated my question with Gradle deployNodes task. I run the nodes using usual build/nodes/runnodes command. To trigger the flow, I issue a http request: "http:localhost:10029/api/testapp/start-flow?price=10&otherParty=CN=Other,O=Other,L=NY,C=US"

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a couple of problems with the code you posted:

- The annotation should be `@StartableByRPC`, not `@StartableNByRPC`
- The price passed to `startTrackedFlow` should be a long, not an int

However, even after fixing these issues, I couldn't replicate your error. Can you apply these fixes, do a clean re-deploy of your nodes (`gradlew clean deployNodes`), and see whether the error changes?

Comment: Thanks for looking into the problem. I made the fixes and did gradlew clean deployNodes. But, I see same error. Do I need to add the nodes as part of permissions in deployNodes task ? or am I missing any other step ?

Comment: Can you update the code samples in the question to correct the errors and show how you get the other party in the API?

Comment: Corrected the code samples and added code to get the other Party.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be connecting to the other node via RPC. RPC is how a node's owner speaks to their node. In the real world, you wouldn't have the other node's RPC credentials, and couldn't log into the node in this way.

Instead, you should use your own node's RPC client to retrieve the counterparty's identity:

`val otherParty = services.partyFromX500Name("CN=Other,O=Other,L=NY,C=US")!!`

See an M14 example here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-M14/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/api/ExampleApi.kt.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.